# R ggplot troubleshoot geom_line with grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble to make both geom_lines for both the filtered on groups appear when I run the following code (can share the csv if the data is needed to make troubleshoot easier).

I've read through earlier stackoverflow questions and suggestions were to make sure there is a group = " " and color = " " in the aes, which I've done.  Not sure where else to tweak.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

zillow_data <- read.csv("C:/published_apps/multi_app_zillow - zestimates/data/zillow_data.csv", 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

#zillow_zestimate_sales
zillow_zestimate_sales <- filter(zillow_data,
                                 grepl("zestimate", zillow_data$type))

all <- zillow_zestimate_sales
all$date <- as.Date(all$Date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
all$beds <- as.numeric(all$beds)
all <- all %>% mutate(year = year(all$date))

plotbycity1 <- all %>%  
  filter(beds ==1) %>%
  ungroup() 

plotbycity <- plotbycity1 %>% 
  group_by(city, year) %>%
  filter(city %in% c("Arlington", "Watertown")) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(median_rent = median(Value), count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() 

ggplot(plotbycity, 
       aes(x = year, y = median_rent, group = city, 
           color = city, text = paste('obs: ', count))) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))+    
  ggtitle("Median Zestimates")
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to troubleshoot if you provide the results of `dput(plotbycity)`, since that's what you're feeding into `ggplot()`.

Comment: or at least `str(plotbycity)` ...

Comment: Sure, can replace following as a test dataframe for zillow_zestimate_sales.    
                                                                             
zillow_zestimate_sales<-data.frame(Date=c("8/31/2017", "8/31/2017","7/31/2016", "7/31/2016", "6/30/2015", "6/30/2015"),
                                   Value=c(373600, 372600, 370400, 366300, 362000, 357400),
                                   beds=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
                                   city=c("Arlington","Watertown","Arlington","Watertown","Arlington","Watertown"))

Comment: However it works with the test df, so maybe root cause of ggplot issues is the csv.  Will continue to investigate but if any obvious errors become more apparent, please let me know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a minus symbol in your file name? It would be better if you didn't include all of the spaces and symbols in your file names. I would double check that you are getting exactly what you think you are when you read in the file. Also I'd suggest try using readr::read_csv() to read your files in. Will attempt to correctly parse your data automatically and makes StringsAsFactors() irrelevant.